# "GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES" was not declared in this scope & others

Tags: c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

So i'm trying to use the `glPixelStorei` methods from OpenGL ES 2.0 in an NDK plugin i'm writing. After some fiddling with the includes, I can get it doing most things i want. However, there is an ongoing issue with getting the defined macros like in the title to work. Currently, eclipse is producing errors like the title for each of the macros in the first arguments of each call below:

```
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_FALSE );
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_LSB_FIRST,  GL_TRUE  );
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0 );
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
```

However, it shows `glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 0);` as error-free and even tells me `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` has a value of (`0x0CF5`). It will build fine without the above lines, but they provide some necessary functionality, so fixing it is the priority.

I have included: `#include <GLES2/gl2.h>` and `#include <EGL/egl.h>`

Am I missing an include for macro definitions or is this an issue with OpenGL ES? I noticed after looking at the header files, there are no definitions for the problem macros.

I wasn't sure how best to word this issue so i do apologize if this has been asked before, but i was not able to find any questions on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to your problem.

OpenGL ES2.0 supports the glPixelStorei function call but the only allowed parameter is GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT with arguments 1,2,4 and 8. (you're passing 0 which is not valid!).

Comment: Oh, i hadn't come across that anywhere. Is there a workaround for similar functionality? Perhaps a different version of Open GL?